# Is there a way to force a C++ compiler to store a variable in a register?

Tags: c++, cpu-registers

I know that the `inline` keyword makes the compiler more likely to inline a function, although the decision is up to the compiler, and the GNU extension `__attribute__((always_inline))` forces the compiler to inline it.
Correspondingly, is there...

```
__attribute__((always_register)) register int foo = 678;
```

...or something like that?

Comment: What would happen if you `always_register` more variables than there are registers?

Comment: @RaymondChen The same thing that would happen if it's not possible to inline a function marked `always_inline`.

Comment: *force* hopefully no, the compiler knows better than you what to do, you are not sure to have enough registers for the rest of the code, and when you call a function/method the called cannot know a register is 'reserved' so the value must be saved elsewhere

Comment: If you need this level of control, write it in assembler yourself.  If this is for perf reasons, trust the compiler or write it in assembly yourself.

Comment: There was a keyword (there still is, but it's now deprecated) called `register` that gave the compiler a _hint_ that it would be a good idea to store something in a register. Nowadays people mostly rely on the compilers optimization to figure out what's best.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I'm asking out of curiosity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC has a way to specify register for a local variable through usage of keywords [`asm` and `register`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html):

```
register int *foo asm ("r12");
```

Note the quote:

> The only supported use for this feature is to specify registers for
>   input and output operands when calling Extended `asm`.

This feature is used in Linux kernel on some architectures to gain access to a thread-local storage that is stored in one of general purpose registers. This is how `current` macro is implemented on [ARC architecture](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7-rc5/source/arch/arc/include/asm/current.h#L17):

```
register struct task_struct *curr_arc asm("r25");
#define current (curr_arc)
```

Such usage is interesting as it uses `register` keyword at a global scope, while in standard C it can only be used locally.

Comment: Very interesting.  This answer might be valuable in the duplicate as well.

Comment: Will this throw C++14/17/... errors with register being no longer a valid keyword?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan This is an extension, so I don't think it should. GCC doesn't seem to generate any errors/warnings.